# Change appearance of italic \ae symbol

Tags: symbols, italic

I need to use `\ae` symbol in my article both in standard and italic forms.

Text `\ae\textit{\ae}`in my .tex file looks like this

[image]

The italic symbol seems unfamiliar when it's a small letter on a page. Is there a way to change its appearance so it will be, for example, like this one ?

[image]

The document has the following content

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,book,a5paper]{ncc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}

\section*{Введение}
...
\ae \textit{\ae}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really font-dependent. Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can see the environment of the problem?

Comment: @Rmano sure, in a minute

Comment: @Rmano I added the content

Comment: how did you generate the desired image? You can probably use the same font. The question is just about font choice (la)tex doesn't really have any control over this,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I generated it in overleaf.com with pdfLaTex compiler and Tex Live 2020 version.

Comment: no, your second image that you say you want `\ae` to look like not the first image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a better shape with

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,book,a5paper]{ncc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\let\tg\relax\let\ctg\relax
\let\arctg\relax\let\arcctg\relax

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ae}{T1}

\begin{document}

\section*{Введение}

\ae \textit{\ae}

\end{document}
```

The two `\let` lines are to avoid four error messages one gets because `ncc` wants to define things that are defined by `babel-russian` afterwards.

[image]

Comment: For me...it is absolutely perfect! "Identico" :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!

Answer (score 0):

And a solution based on @egreg’s that uses Unicode OpenType fonts and runs in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,book,a5paper]{ncc}
\tracinglostchars=2
\let\tg\relax\let\ctg\relax
\let\arctg\relax\let\arcctg\relax

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures=Common]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common]{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}
          {CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}

\section*{Введение}
...
\ae \textit{\ae}
...
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Serif sample]